# jquery for loop, appending divs but can only append text to the first created div whyy

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
var numPills = 3
 
 for(var i=0; i< numPills; i++){
  //var currentPill = JUser.pill1.;
  $(".col-r-in").append(
   $('<div/>')
    .attr("id", "medsProgress")
    .addClass("roundedBar")
  );

  $('#medsProgress').append(
   $('<div/>')
    .attr("id", "medsBar")
  );

  $('#medsBar').append(
   $('<p/>')
    .attr("id", "appendPillName")
  );
  $('#appendPillName').append("test");
  
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="medsProgress" class="roundedBar">
    <div id="medsBar">
    <p id="appendPillName">test test test</p>
    <p id="appendPillName"></p>
    <p id="appendPillName"></p>
    </div>
    <div id="medsBar"></div>
    <div id="medsBar"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="medsProgress" class="roundedBar"></div>
    <div id="medsProgress" class="roundedBar"></div>
    </div>
```

Ok so in this for loop I am displaying 3 divs, that works well but the last append only appends the text "test" to only the first dive below is what the output is in html

it only adds the p tag to the first div created and the text is only applied to that first p tag :(

Comment: No duplicate IDs!

Comment: `id="appendPillName"` cannot be repeated. id must be unique. All your ids are repeated, instead use class.

Comment: `id` must be unique in a single document. Use class instead.

Comment: Easier option will be to use `append` only one with all the required markup framed only once..

Comment: use this code     $('.appendPillName').append("test");

Comment: <p class="appendPillName">test test test</p>
<p class="appendPillName"></p>
<p class="appendPillName"></p>

Comment: try to create unique `id` like `'medsProgress_' + i` which will give you `medsProgress_0`, `medsProgress_1` and so on. Follow same for inner `div` too.

Answer (score 0):

You are using ids that should be unique so the browser selects the first element with that id

a cleaner way to do this is:

```
for(var i=0; i< numPills; i++){
    $(".col-r-in").append('<div id="medsProgress class="roundedBar"><div id="medsBar"><p id="appendPillName">test</p></div></div>');

}
```

or remove/change the ids entirely

```
 for(var i=0; i< numPills; i++){
        $(".col-r-in").append('<div class="medsProgress roundedBar"><div class="medsBar"><p class="appendPillName">test</p></div></div>');

    }
```

Comment: Your 'cleaner' way still uses duplicate IDs

Comment: @AndrewL. yes but doesn't create the same problem because we append to a class not to a id

Comment: I see that, but you still shouldn't include duplicate IDs. That's very bad practice

Answer (score 0):

you appended 3 times div id is "medsProgress",but you use jquery find the div by id,it only can find the first div which id is medsProgress.

Answer (score 0):

Refere [Jquery DOC](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

> Each id value must be used only once within a document. If more than
>   one element has been assigned the same ID, queries that use that ID
>   will only select the first matched element in the DOM. This behavior
>   should not be relied on, however; a document with more than one
>   element using the same ID is invalid.

For your solution you can use `:last` psudo selector and child element by id selector.

```js
var numPills = 3

for(var i=0; i< numPills; i++){
    //var currentPill = JUser.pill1.;
    $(".col-r-in").append(
        $('<div/>')
            .attr("class", "medsProgress")
            .addClass("roundedBar")
    );

    $('.medsProgress:last').append(
        $('<div/>')
            .attr("id", "medsBar")
    );

    $('.medsProgress:last #medsBar').append(
        $('<p/>')
            .attr("id", "appendPillName")
    );
    $('.medsProgress:last #appendPillName').append("test");

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-r-in">
</div>
```